# PHP json_encode not working with apostrophe

Tags: php

I try to json encode an array, It always works unless there is a string ANYWHERE in the array that contains this exact apostrophe "`’`"

I tried to string replace it but it doesn't work...

```
        $thistrack = str_replace('’','',$thistrack);
        $thistrack = str_replace('\u2019','',$thistrack);
        $thistrack = str_replace('\0092','',$thistrack);
        $thistrack = str_replace('\\\\u0027','',$thistrack);
```

In this case. $thistrack contains the following:
`var_dump($thistrack);`
[image: Var_Dump]

In the end, this is what i'd like to achieve.

```
$savestuff = file_put_contents($savepath.'history.rhr', json_encode($completehistory));
```

But the file is empty, this ALWAYS happens when there is a `’` somewhere in the array...

Comment: Try to replace `chr(146)`.  `chr(145)` will replace the other one.

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: Thank you @AbraCadaver this was it!